# Java Glassfish sudden and persistent slowdown

Tags: java, performance, glassfish

I have a java web application running in Glassfish 3.1 that is load balanced between 5 servers. Occasionally, a single server will start taking up to 5 times as long as the others to process requests. It will continue this poor performance until it has been restarted. After a quick restart of Glassfish the server begins responding as normal.

During a slow period I have connected to the VM with jVisualvm and everything seemed to be working as expected. There was no prolonged garbage collection and no stuck threads. Also there was plenty of heap head space. I also connected to glassfish admin console and that was running slow as well. The slowness appears to be VM wide.

What could cause VM wide general sluggishness?

Thread Dump:
[Dump file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/175b2Dy120vTUwyuJnSaeqNqobH0bGQYpQ9S_SwYWsl4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: on a sluggish run, generate a thread dump and post it `asadmin generate-jvm-report --type=thread`

Comment: I added a link to a thread dump generated with the command you suggested